# Finding variables of both sides of a paralellogram

Tags: geometry

[image]

How am I supposed to find $x$ or $y$ when I can't set them equal to anything?

Comment: Use the fact that parallel sides of parallelograms are equal to each other and that line segment AC bisects line segment DB.

Answer (score 0):

As @Houdineo said in the comments , we use the following facts :-

$\bullet$ The opposite sides of a parallelogram are parallel and equal .

$  \bullet$ The diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other .

Thus , we obtain :- $$6x+12=5y+3$$ $$4y-9=2x+15$$

From these two equations , we obtain $x=\boxed 6 $ and $y=\boxed 9$